# Why are Xandarians in a hurry to get to nothing at all?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, dialogue, guardians-of-the-galaxy

Near the start of Guardians Of The Galaxy, Rocket says about the Xandarians:

> Xandarians. What a bunch of losers. All of them in a big hurry to get from something stupid, to nothing at all. Pathetic.

What does he mean by this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

He's merely being insulting about Xandarian society.

Xandar seems to be an advanced, wealthy, industrial civilization, with a strong rule of law.

From Rocket's point of view, as an outsider on the edges of the law, Xandarians seem to be busy and hard working, but he thinks their life is boring and meaningless. We also know that Rocket feels like an outsider and falls back on put-downs and sarcasm when talking to friends and foes alike - so him being insulting to Xandarians isn't surprising.

Answer (score 2):

He literally saying that Xandarians have no goal at all or a goal that is something that life is not worth for.

And every Xandarian who wants to achieve something is in hurry to do so.

So, he is in a way describing what Xandarians are and making fun of them like he does later when he says that a guy committed a crime by keeping that hairstyle, and that girl who needs help to climb down that small stair.

Answer (score 1):

Rocket is bit of a misanthrope.

He's not a fan of people in general, and has shown that he considers himself an outsider.  As he is an outsider, he feels free to comment on those he sees, and because he's a sarcastic type, it's rarely complimentary when he does.  He considers that the daily business the Xandarians are going about to simply be meaningless and pointless, and takes the view that they should just be mocked for it.